# How to get the activity indicator to run on the bottom of the collectionview to indicate that more items are being loaded?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, collectionview, activity-indicator

I was wondering how I could add an activity indicator to the footer of the collection view in Xamarin Forms to show that more items are being fetched from the server.

XAML

```xml
<CollectionView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="Posts" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="Posts_SelectionChanged" RemainingItemsThreshold="5" RemainingItemsThresholdReached="Posts_RemainingItemsThresholdReached">
  <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout Padding="8, 8, 8, 0">
                // Some XAML
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Comment: Try [Sharpnado.HorizontalListView](https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.HorizontalListView), keyword: InfiniteListLoader.

Comment: Thanks @Shaw. I will have a look at it.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use Threshold in CollectionView with Activity Indicator and set IsVisible equals true for Activity Indicator when you Thresholding your data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).